# Why can I call DBMS_SESSION subprograms without EXECUTE privilege?

Tags: oracle

I execute the following SQL to confirm I don't have privileges to DBMS_SESSION package:

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'MY_USER' AND TABLE_NAME = 'DBMS_SESSION' AND GRANTOR = 'SYS';
```

No rows are returned, so why am I able to call this successfully?

```
SELECT DBMS_SESSION.UNIQUE_SESSION_ID FROM DUAL;
```

| UNIQUE_SESSION_ID |
| --- |
| 0029D4020001 |

Moreover, I can compile a package with DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT, and use it without problems.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE CANCELLATION_TOKEN AS
  NAMESPACE CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) := 'CANCELLATION_TOKEN';
  FUNCTION isSignalled(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN;
  PROCEDURE wait_for(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE clear(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2);
  PROCEDURE signal(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2);
END CANCELLATION_TOKEN;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY CANCELLATION_TOKEN AS
  FUNCTION isSignalled(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN AS
  BEGIN
    RETURN SYS_CONTEXT(NAMESPACE, in_token_name) = '1';
  END isSignalled;

  PROCEDURE wait_for(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.set_context(NAMESPACE, in_token_name, '-1');
  END wait_for;

  PROCEDURE clear(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.set_context(NAMESPACE, in_token_name, '0');
  END clear;

  PROCEDURE signal(in_token_name IN VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.set_context(NAMESPACE, in_token_name, '1');
  END signal;
END CANCELLATION_TOKEN;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE CONTEXT CANCELLATION_TOKEN USING CANCELLATION_TOKEN ACCESSED GLOBALLY;
```

I'm quite confused, since even the [Database Security Guide / Part III Controlling Access to Data / 14 Using Application Contexts to Retrieve User Information / 14.4 Global Application Contexts / 14.4.6 PL/SQL Package to Manage a Global Application Context / 14.4.6.1 About the Package That Manages the Global Application Context](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/dbseg/using-application-contexts-to-retrieve-user-information.html#GUID-280970AB-BC5E-40FE-85A3-3724017E9417) states the following:

> You must have the EXECUTE privilege for the DBMS_SESSION package before you use its procedures. Typically, you create and store this package in the database schema of a security administrator. The SYS schema owns the DBMS_SESSION package.

But it works without the EXECUTE privilege! Can you help me understand why, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Execute privilege may not be granted to you, specifically, but did you check to see to whom *is* it granted?

```
SELECT GRANTEE 
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'DBMS_SESSION' 
AND GRANTOR = 'SYS'
ORDER BY 1 ;

+---------+
| GRANTEE |
+---------+
| AUDSYS  |
| DVSYS   |
| PUBLIC  |   <-- Ah ha! 
| SYSRAC  |
+---------+
```